# Svelte / SvelteKit and Typescript: add properties to the window object, or extend the interface

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I have the following working (running) code but am getting the TypeScript error *Property 'onSubmit' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.*.

```
function onSubmit() {
  . . .
}

onMount(() => {
  window.onSubmit = onSubmit; <-- Error
});

onDestroy(() => {
  window.onSubmit = null; <-- Error
});
```

In my *global.d.ts* file I have tried exporting an interface to import

```
export interface CustomWindow extends Window {
  onSubmit: () => void;
}
```

and declaring a global

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    onSubmit: () => void;
  }
}
```

Neither solution has been successful, the error persists. How can we add properties to the window object for TypeScript to recognize?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost correct, `declare` is the correct keyword, you don't need to wrap it with `global` though.

The following adds it:

```js
declare interface Window {
  onSubmit: () => void;
}
```

Also make sure you don't have any `import`s or `export`s in your `global.d.ts` as then it's no longer treated as an ambient module.